# Autofill Values in Pandas Column trying to achieve an equal Split

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataset shown below (sample):

```
MasterID MyId Score Color   Myset
100      123    34    Red    TRAIN
100      234    45    Pink   TRAIN
100      345    67    Blue   TRAIN
110      456    75    Green  TEST
115      567    36    Pink   
115      678    78    Blue   
104      679    35    Green  
104      569    78    Pink   
106      387    77    Blue   
106      388    76    Pink   
121      390    86    Red    
122      450    94    Pink   
123      333    102   Blue   
123      222    111   Yellow
```

I want to Autofill Values in 'Myset' column as 'TRAIN' and 'TEST' such that the overall records has equal split if possible or closeby ; given that a single masterid will only belong to one set.

What I have tried so far ; I am filtering out the records where Myset is 'Null' and then using
GroupShuffleSplit() to split and later on merging it with the original dataset to fill the values in Myset. However this is not what I want

```
df = main[main.Myset.isnull()] 

from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit 

splitter = GroupShuffleSplit(test_size=.50, n_splits=1, random_state = 7)
split = splitter.split(df, groups=df['MasterID'])
train_inds, test_inds = next(split)
```

A possible expected output :

```
MasterID MyId Score Color   Myset
100      123    34    Red    TRAIN
100      234    45    Pink   TRAIN
100      345    67    Blue   TRAIN
110      456    75    Green  TEST
115      567    36    Pink   TRAIN
115      678    78    Blue   TRAIN
104      679    35    Green  TRAIN
104      569    78    Pink   TRAIN
106      387    77    Blue   TEST
106      388    76    Pink   TEST
121      390    86    Red    TEST
122      450    94    Pink   TEST
123      333    102   Blue   TEST
123      222    111   Yellow TEST
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to group the dataframe by `MasterID`, then use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.choices) to generate a list of `TRAIN` or `TEST` values and use that to fill the empty `Myset` values in the groupby object and then merge those values back to the original dataframe:

```py
import random

grps = main.groupby('MasterID')['Myset']
rand = random.choices(['TRAIN', 'TEST'], k=len(grps))
grps = grps.first().fillna(dict(zip(grps.groups, rand)))
main = main.merge(grps, left_on='MasterID', right_index=True, suffixes=('_x', '')).drop('Myset_x', axis=1)
```

Sample output:

```
    MasterID  MyId  Score   Color  Myset
0        100   123     34     Red  TRAIN
1        100   234     45    Pink  TRAIN
2        100   345     67    Blue  TRAIN
3        110   456     75   Green   TEST
4        115   567     36    Pink  TRAIN
5        115   678     78    Blue  TRAIN
6        104   679     35   Green   TEST
7        104   569     78    Pink   TEST
8        106   387     77    Blue   TEST
9        106   388     76    Pink   TEST
10       121   390     86     Red  TRAIN
11       122   450     94    Pink   TEST
12       123   333    102    Blue  TRAIN
13       123   222    111  Yellow  TRAIN
```

Another alternative is to build up a similar list of random choices, then map that to a dict of index/choice pairs and use that with [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```py
grps = main.groupby('MasterID')['Myset']
rand = random.choices(['TRAIN', 'TEST'], k=len(grps))
dd = dict(zip(grp.groups, rand))
d3 = { k : dd[v] for k, v in zip(main.index, main['MasterID']) }
main['Myset'] = grps.transform(lambda x:x.fillna(d3))
```

Results are similar to the above.

Comment: Hi @Nick thanks for the reply but you are not using masterID. For example: 104 belongs to both train and test set in your answer. I have mentioned above that a single masterid will only belong to one set.

Comment: @Ash apologies, I didn't read the question carefully enough... let me think about it...

Comment: @Ash see my edit. There's a couple of alternative solutions...